# Python Input does not show when opening project with double click

Tags: python, input

I am trying to create a simple stand-alone python program which runs perfectly on PyCharm:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


filename = input("Enter CSV filename from folder: ")
file = pd.read_csv(filename)

team_1_name = input("Enter Team 1 name for comparison: ")
team_2_name = input("Enter Team 2 name for comparison: ")

team_1 = file.loc[file.Club == team_1_name]
team_2 = file.loc[file.Club == team_2_name]

labels = [team_1_name, team_2_name]
plt.boxplot([team_1.Overall, team_2.Overall], labels = labels)
plt.show()
```

However, when I try to doubleclick and execute the Python project from the Windows Explorer, it does not open the Input Window as requested. When I comment out the import statements, it does ask for the inputs. The same is happening when I use pyinstaller to convert it to a .exe
Can someone explain me why the input command does not show up when I use import parameters and run the program outside of PyCharm?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Is it saved as .py or as .pyw? Pyw's usually don't open up a terminal

Comment: Cannot reproduce: When I save this code as `SO.py` and run it (by double-clicking) on Windows 10, I get `Enter CSV filename from folder: ` as expected.

Comment: You can also add `print("before")` before the import statement for debugging purposes.

Comment: It's saved as py.
@Brambor this is odd. For me the terminal just opens for a brief moment and directly closes again. And printing "before" does work without any bugs

Comment: @Brambor which program do you run it on? Do I need to change anything in my settings?

Comment: if it opens and closes do this: 1) open cmd.exe (I expect you know how). 2) drag the file onto the opened cmd, this will paste its path into it 3) press enter to run it. Now error or something will show. Maybe different python runs it if you double click versus when you execute it in your code editor.

Comment: Also, you can `right click the .py file > edit in IDLE > chose IDLE` Then f5 to run it. Does it show correctly?

Comment: Thanks @Brambor for the advice! After I run it in the cmd, it told me the pandas module and afterwards the matplotlib module have not been installed. I did not know it's possible to have these modules installed in PyCharm but still need to install them again. Now it works for me ;)

Comment: You have multiple Python installations. You can see all of them in windows variable PATH (write `path` into cmd.exe). If you can see only one there, maybe your PyCharm really stores its own python. Anyway, you should be able to find it (google it). I think you would rather use the same Python in cmd.exe & in PyCharm.